# Tezos version running

Tags: tezos-client

When running node it is useful to know which version you're running so you're up to date. Does anyone know which command do I have to execute to know which version of Tezos I am running? Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

There is an RPC for this now, merged [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/883).

It is [GET /monitor/commit_hash](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-monitor-commit-hash) and it just returns the commit hash as a JSON string.

You can also see this in `tezos-node --help | tail -n 1`.

(Of course, one also needs to make sure any `tezos-client` and daemons are at a compatible version. These don't seem to know their own commit hash yet.)

Answer (score 1):

I use this command inside the folder where I compile the binaries

`git describe --always`

Comment: Thanks for this!